# psql SQL STATE[08006] Password Authentication Failed for User. Laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql

This is my first time working with Laravel, and I have a project set up, but I cannot connect to the database I created in Postgres. Whenever I try to connect to the database for a query (or anything), I get this error:

```py
PDOException
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "marlie" FATAL: password authentication failed for user "marlie"
```

I'm using Windows 10, PostgreSQL 11, Laravel 6.0.4. I can connect to the database through pgAdmin4, command line, and psycopg2 without any password authentication issues. Only Laravel is giving me a hard time.

I've tried creating a new Laravel project, creating a new superuser (which I've tested, can successfully access the database from the other programs I mentioned above). I've also tried putting the username and password in both single and double quotes. I tried changing the database name to the OID number value in my postgreSQL file for the database. I've also tried adding the absolute file directory. I've tried changing port from 5432 to 54320. I've also tried other passwords.

Some search results suggested I play with the pg_hba.conf file and adding some lines such as (the indentation here is a little funny, but in the actual file it's all lined up):

```py
local   all     marlie                  md5
local   all     marlie                  trust
host    all     all     ::1/0           trust
host    all     all     all         trust
```

I've also tried changing everything to trust, in which case I can log in from command line without a password, but Laravel still won't let me! Also, my Windows laptop doesn't seem to support local connections since they're Unix-socket domains, so any local entries in pg_hba.conf end with the file not being able to load at all. Currently, my pg_hba.conf file is back to the default settings.

I've tried logging in by ssh into my Laravel project through Homestead.

```py
$ vagrant ssh
$ psql -d natureFun -U marlie -W
Password:
psql: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "marlie"
```

I thought this was interesting because nowhere in my conf file do I say to use peer authentication. I've only ever tried trust and md5.

This is my .env file from Laravel

```py
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=natureFun
DB_USERNAME=marlie
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

This is pg_hba.conf

```py
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: If `peer` authentication is mentioned and you don't have it in `pg_hba.conf`, you may need to verify 1) you're editing the right `pg_hba.conf` file (I've seen some installs where there are multiple `$PGDATA` directories, but only one is actually used), 2) that the `reload` is actually happening (should see a `SIGHUP` message in the Postgres logs

Comment: I've searched my computer for other pg_hba.conf files, and this is the only one. And I checked the log, SIGHUP is there after reload

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your first `pg_hba.conf` has a typo:

```
host    all     all     all         trust
```

Should be:

```
host    all     all     <ip_address>/<netmask>         trust
```

If it's a dev machine and you don't care about security (for now), just try:

```
host    all     all     0.0.0.0/0         trust
```

Also, unless you're acutally using IPv6, I'd recommend getting rid of the entire line containing `::1/0`

Your second `pg_hba.conf` that you pasted should work, given that you restarted/reloaded the `postmaster` process -- you can usually do that through `pg_ctl reload` from the terminal or `SELECT pg_reload_conf()` from `psql`

Disclosure: I am an [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://enterprisedb.com) employee

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the line with 0.0.0.0/0 trust did not change the error after reloading with pg_ctl. I also tried it with commenting out the IPv6 line, but the same error as before. Thank you, though!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! I misunderstood how Homestead worked (and also failed to mention that I am using it, sorry!)
when I put localhost or 127.0.0.1 in my .env file in my Laravel project, it references the Homestead Virtual as the localhost, NOT my actual computer.
Changing DB_HOST to my computer's IP address solved the problem and I am now happily connected.